# How do I sum values of groups based off if group is in a specified list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (data2) consisting of many different Manufacturers' sales orders with a column called 'num units sold_x'.

If the Manufacturer name exists in a list called Dataman:

I want to update the value of 'num units sold_x' in each row by taking the sum of column in the dataframe called 'EQTUnit' **for each particular Manufacturer**. It is fine if all the rows for a particular Manufacturer has the same 'num units sold_x' field since this is the sum of 'EQTUnit' for each Manufacturer.

I think it sounds simple but can't seem to wrap my head around this problem. This is what I have so far:

```
for index,row in data2.iterrows():
    for x in dataman:
        if data2.loc[index, 'EQTMan'] in dataman:
            data2.loc[index, 'num units sold_x'] = data2[data2['EQTMan'] == x].EQTUnit.sum()
```

Here is some sample data:

```
    UCCStatus   UCCDate     EQTMan  EQTUnit
0   SALE        5/20/2019   SPARTAN 1
1   SALE        5/28/2019   SPARTAN 2
2   SALE        5/29/2019   SPARTAN 1
3   SALE        5/25/2019   SPARTAN 1
4   TERMINATI   7/16/2019   JOHNSON 11
5   SALE        8/8/2019    SPARTAN 1
6   TERMINATI   9/17/2019   SPARTAN 1
7   SALE        8/16/2019   TITAN   2
8   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
9   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
```

Basically, I need to frequently update the 'num units sold_x' field by taking the sum of 'EQTUnit' for each unique Manufacturer.

Expected Output:

```
   UCCStatus    UCCDate     EQTMan  EQTUnit num units sold_x
0   SALE        5/20/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
1   SALE        5/28/2019   SPARTAN 2       7
2   SALE        5/29/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
3   SALE        5/25/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
4   TERMINATI   7/16/2019   JOHNSON 11      11
5   SALE        8/8/2019    SPARTAN 1       7
6   TERMINATI   9/17/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
7   SALE        8/16/2019   TITAN   2   
8   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2   
9   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
```

Comment: could you provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Can you please check now if it's clearer?

Comment: What is your expected output? Something like my answer? Can you include that in the same format that I have pasted the input data? Please don't post images on StackOverflow. I have edited your question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for David - thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` to filter for rows by using `.isin()` against the `dataman` list to see if they are in the dataframe.

Then use `.groupby` and `transform` on that filtered dataset.

input:

```
    UCCStatus   UCCDate     EQTMan  EQTUnit
0   SALE        5/20/2019   SPARTAN 1
1   SALE        5/28/2019   SPARTAN 2
2   SALE        5/29/2019   SPARTAN 1
3   SALE        5/25/2019   SPARTAN 1
4   TERMINATI   7/16/2019   JOHNSON 11
5   SALE        8/8/2019    SPARTAN 1
6   TERMINATI   9/17/2019   SPARTAN 1
7   SALE        8/16/2019   TITAN   2
8   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
9   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
```

code:

```
dataman = ['SPARTAN', 'JOHNSON']
data2['num units sold_x'] = ''
data2.loc[data2['EQTMan'].isin(dataman), 'num units sold_x'] = 
data2.loc[data2['EQTMan'].isin(dataman)].groupby('EQTMan')['EQTUnit'].transform('sum')
data2
```

output:

```
   UCCStatus    UCCDate     EQTMan  EQTUnit num units sold_x
0   SALE        5/20/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
1   SALE        5/28/2019   SPARTAN 2       7
2   SALE        5/29/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
3   SALE        5/25/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
4   TERMINATI   7/16/2019   JOHNSON 11      11
5   SALE        8/8/2019    SPARTAN 1       7
6   TERMINATI   9/17/2019   SPARTAN 1       7
7   SALE        8/16/2019   TITAN   2   
8   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2   
9   SALE        8/5/2019    TITAN   2
```